# Dynamic SQL Concatenation with PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am writing a PHP prepared statement using MySQLi prepared statements where the first bound parameter is a user's ID and the second parameter can be one of 5 different pieces of SQL code (the **$redeemLimitCheckRange** variable) based on other conditions represented as a string.  I am having trouble binding the second parameter.

I have tried binding the SQL code as a string, have tried using the SQL CONCAT() function, but neither seem to work.

```
<?php
    if($dbRedeemStart != '' && $dbRedeemEnd != ''){
        $redeemLimitCheckRange = "AND DATE(chg_date) >='$dbRedeemStart' AND DATE(chg_date) <= '$dbRedeemEnd'";
    else if($dbRedeemStart != '' && $dbRedeemEnd == ''){                                                                                                                      
        $redeemLimitCheckRange = "AND DATE(chg_date) >= '$dbRedeemStart'";
    else if($dbRedeemStart == '' && $dbRedeemEnd != ''){
        $redeemLimitCheckRange = "AND DATE(chg_date) <= '$dbRedeemEnd'";
    }else{
        $redeemLimitCheckRange = "";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(recId) totalRedeem FROM transactions WHERE userId = ? AND `type` = 'Redeemed' ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        error_log("mysqli_stmt_prepare failure", 0);
    }else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $usrId, $redeemLimitCheckRange);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $rslt = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
?>
```

Currently, php is failing on the mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql) line and throwing an error.

Comment: no you cant do this, concatenate the `$redeemLimitCheckRange` string to the `$sql` sting

Comment: Don't wrap chg_date in the `DATE()` function. Assuming its a date SQL type, just leave it as such.

Comment: @tim thanks.  Why is this not allowed with prepared statements?

Comment: parameters are bound, not large chunks of a query `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(recId) totalRedeem FROM transactions WHERE userId = ? AND `type` = 'Redeemed' ".$redeemLimitCheckRange;` then fix the bind_param as you only have one